# How to turn $.each object to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a json, I `$.each` `videolist` and try to get the `second`. Then, I wish to turn the `second` into array[], easy for me to do next function that I want. Just not sure how to turn it into array.

```js
var videoinfo = [{
    "startdatetime": "2014-12-21 00:23:14",
    "totalsecondrun": "2019402310",
    "videolist": [{
        "videoid": "uoSDF234",
        "second": "10"
    }, {
        "videoid": "0apq3ss",
        "second": "14"
    }]
}];


var calduration = function() {

    var list = videoinfo[0].videolist;

    $.each(list, function(index, value) {
        alert($.makeArray(value.second));
    });

};

calduration();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I expected the output should be [10,14].

Comment: I don't get it, you expected to only get one alert with both values when you iterate with `each` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the 'second' property for each video list object read ino an array? If so just define an array and push that value into it in each iteration. FYI, you don't have JSON you have a java array/object literal.

Comment: @adeneo hi, if not using `each` what function can I use, please suggest to me . thanks

Comment: `map` comes to mind, see the answer below ?

Comment: `var arr = videoinfo[0].videolist.map(function(x) { return x.second });`

Comment: @adeneo someone answer bellow is work, how bout make `videoid` to array same way ?

Comment: `var arr = videoinfo[0].videolist.map(function(x) { return x.videoid });`

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a `$.each()` loop, as you title implies, here is one approach:

```
var calduration = function () {
    var duration = [];
    $.each(videoinfo[0].videolist, function (index, value) {
        duration.push(parseInt(value.second, 10));
    });

    return duration;
};
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/znnha79y/)

---

I'd suggest using [**`$.map()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), though:

```
var calduration = function () {
    return $.map(videoinfo[0].videolist, function (value, index) {
        return parseInt(value.second, 10);
    });
};
```

..or [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
return videoinfo[0].videolist.map(function (value, index) {
    return parseInt(value.second, 10);
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mo4rucco/)

---

And if you want to use plain JS:

```
var calduration = function () {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(videoinfo[0].videolist, function(value){
        return parseInt(value.second, 10);
    });
};
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hwmxb69/)

Comment: should I put like this `var timers = [calduration()];` ?

Comment: sorry my fault is `var timers = calduration();` , if I want `videoid` to array just change `return parseInt(value.second, 10);` to `return parseInt(value.videoid, 10);` ?